# How to force Java Mail to use XOAUTH2 mechanism instead of PLAIN?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, sasl

I am trying to use Java Mail to connect to an IMAP server using XOAUTH2. The configuration is as follows:

```
Properties properties= new Properties();
properties.put("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
properties.put("mail.imap.auth.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");
properties.put("mail.imap.auth.login.disable", true);
properties.put("mail.imap.auth.plain.disable", true);
properties.put("mail.imap.auth.xoauth2.disable", false);
properties.put("mail.debug", "true");
properties.put("mail.debug.auth", "true");
                
Session session = Session.getInstance(properties);
store = session.getStore("imaps");
store.connect(host, username, accessToken);
```

As you can see, I am using all the properties to avoid any connection using another mechanism different than XOAUTH2, but the debug shows that `AUTHENTICATE PLAIN` is used instead of `AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2`:

[image]

The dependency used in POM is the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Finally, I can authenticate using openssl directly by using `AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2`:

[image]

What I am doing wrong? How can I make Java Mail uses the command `AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2` instead of `AUTHENTICATE PLAIN`?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like what you have should work... That said, is it important which authentication mechanism you use? PLAIN AUTH is fine once the connection is over ssl.

Comment: It seems that the IMAP server works only with XOAUTH2 mechanism. With PLAIN AUTH the authentication fails.

Answer (score 1):

After several hours of working on this, I found that the problem is with the name of the IMAP properties. I changed properties to the following, and now it works:

```
properties.put("mail.imaps.sasl.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");
```

Note that it is not "imap" but "imaps" with an "s" at the end.

I don't know why in many questions in Stackoverflow and the Java Mail documentation the properties appear without the "s" and apparently, it works for them.

[image]

https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/package-summary.html

**Be aware to use a Java Mail Version equal or superior to 1.5.2. I used Java Mail 1.6.2.**

Hope this can help somebody else.